# Not able to login/signup in appwrite console

Tags: flutter, localhost, appwrite

Yesterday i have upgraded my machine and installed everything again. But now i'm not able to login or create new account into the appwrite console. Previously it was working fine. I have checked the documentation but did not get any solution form there.

Error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75guV.png)

Docker version : 4.16.3

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by following steps :

Open cmd and run following steps :

1. run this command
   **docker ps -a**
   it should show something like this if you have installed appwrite correctly.
   [Output for executed command] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kuxo.png
2. Check if docker is running or not by this command **docker compose ls**
   [Output for executed command] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uljt3.png
3. Run **dir appwrite** (for windows) **ls appwrite** (for mac)
   [Output for executed command] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7t01.png

**Now navigate to folder where appwrite is installed** (In my case c:\Users\Admin\appwrite) If you don't know where your appwrite is installed then when you run **dir appwrite** or **ls appwrite** it will show you where your appwrite is installed.

Now run this following commands

1. go into that folder (cd appwrite)
2. remove containers and all data (docker compose down -v)
3. start appwrite again (docker compose up -d)

Done